# Increase Google Cloud Shell Time out time?

Tags: linux, shell, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I am using GCP Cloud Shell for Terminal Access and file editor. The problem I am facing is, if the window is idle for around 5-10minutes, it gets timed out. I am trying to figure out a solution so if the window is left idle for an hour also. It should not get timed out.

I have tried this below command:

`sudo /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=540 net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=540 net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=10`

My understanding is it will wait for 540 sec (keep-alive) then run each probe after every 540 sec (interval) for a defined number of probes.

But this doesn't seem to be working consistently. Sometimes it gets timed out after 20min, something after 8mins.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing the console timed out and keepalive

1. A keepalive (KA) is a message sent by one device to another to check that the link between the two is operating, or to prevent the link from being broken.
2. Session timeout represents the event occuring when a user does not perform any action during an interval

[If you want to edit the session timeout you can edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` configuration file.](https://www.tecmint.com/increase-ssh-connection-timeout/)

Scroll and locate the following parameters:

#ClientAliveInterval

#ClientAliveCountMax

**I am not sure if this is possible inside of gcloud environment**